# Another Multiple IF statements and values in Excel

Tags: excel

```
 _____________________
|A|B|C|D|value|return |
|'''''''''''''|       |
|a|b|a|v|  5  |       |
| | |a|b|  6  |       |
| | |a|c|  7  |       |
```

IF A,B = ANY(C,D) THEN return = value, I tried something like this:

```
=IF(C8=I8:I30;IF(E8=H8:H30;J8:J30;" ");" ")
```

I was looking for solution on stack overflow, and on other websites but I cant find any solution.

For example in this situation I need just "6" in return in a|b|a|v|5|  | row.

Comment: are you expecting a single result from that formulaor an array? Can you indicate the results you expect?

Comment: Your example and your formula don't seem related at all.  Your example seems to show columns A:D + two more columns; your formula refers to columns H:J as well as C and E.  Also, no desired results are shown.

Comment: I edited my question, Ok i know that my formula is bad, and it will not return the value that i wanted to get, can yuo help me then ?

Comment: Have you looked at array formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you mean is that the items you have labeled A are column C, and so forth:  In other words, your worksheet looks like:
[image]

Then try

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C8=H8:H30)*(E8=I8:I30)*J8:J30)
```

Otherwise, clarify.

Note that if E8 contained a 'b', as in your example above, Return would compute to '6'